# Why JFrame is not Maximizing?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, maximize

My First JFrame: Here i am just calling the second JFrame by using

```
new viewxmls().setVisible(true);
```

My Second Jframe (JFrame Name:viewxmls )

```
    public static void main(String args[]) 
     {

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run()
            {
              //  new viewxmls().setVisible(true);
              viewxmls mv1=new viewxmls();
             //mv1.setBounds(200,50,133,122);
              mv1.pack();
             //mv1.setSize(1300,700);
            //mv1.setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);

             mv1.setVisible(true);
             mv1.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH );

            }
         });

      }
```

When i call the second Jframe it becomes very small in size how can i maximize it ?

Here is Jframe image for your review : http://imagesup.net/?di=8136498001116

Any Comments and help. Appreciated. Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set it not to be resizable, you cannot maximize it either.

You also have to set some size for the frame. If you are using some layout managers and have some components added to your frame then just call `frame.pack();`

Otherwise, you need to do either `frame.setSize();` or `frame.setBounds();` which will help you set both location and size.

Comment: hi dan, i made the change which you mentioned but still its not working for me, its still small in size when i call it from another JFrame, But when i run the JFrame alone it is maxmized, Here is Jframe image for your review : imagesup.net/?di=8136498001116

Comment: this code works dan, thank you. public viewxmls() {

        super("MegaViewer");
setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
pack();
setVisible(true);
setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);

Answer (score 0):

```
f.setExtendedState( f.getExtendedState()|JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH );
mv1.setResizable(true);
```

Comment: hi Biswajit, i did what you said but still its not working for me its still small in size when i call it from another JFrame, But when i run the JFrame alone it is maxmized, Here is Jframe image for your review : http://imagesup.net/?di=8136498001116

Comment: set the width of the jframe from where you call this jframe

Comment: i googled what you said, and got this site :https://forums.netbeans.org/topic51560.html , now its working         when i used this code in my second jframe :public viewxmls() {

        super("MegaViewer");
setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
pack();
setVisible(true);
setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);     Thank You Biswajit.